# Does Butterknife leak references after activity finished?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, butterknife

I noticed that even though an activity has been finished Butterknife still holds a reference to it. I even call Butterknife.unbind explicitly on the activity's onDestroy yet these ViewBinder's are still holding onto it.

Here is a pic from the heap dump:

[image]

Any ideas what causes this?